# Создание веб-шрифта из иконок

Tags: html, вёрстка, photoshop

Привет.

Тренируюсь в верстке, нашел в интернете psd-макет с бутстроповской сеткой (12 колонок). В меню хэдэра есть картинки, которые я хочу сделать шрифтом, так как у них цвет меняется при ховере. При использовании inkscape для создания шрифта эти картинки очень коряво векторизируются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я приблизил, чтобы было видно качество картинок. Что делать - не понимаю. я же не буду этот глобус открывать в пейнте и перерисовывать фиолетовым цветом.

Answer (score 1):

Цвет меняется в фотошопе довольно просто. Вообще, лучше всего все иконки делать с помощью [спрайтов](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/). Но если хотите делать шрифтом, то есть прекрасное решение - [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/). Добавляете его как обычные HTMl элементы и стилизуете как обычно.